# Mqtt connection with React native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, mqtt, iot

I am currently making an IoT App that I'm trying to connect to sensors using MQTT. I use the react_native_mqtt package. What I'm trying to achieve is to connect and get the data of topic sent by sensor. but the code unfortunately not working. so What should I update in the app.js file to test the MQTT connection?

Any help is appreciated.

```
import init from 'react-native-mqtt'
    const host = '55.122.xx.xx'


  const port = '1883'
    const clientId = `mqtt_${Math.random().toString(16).slice(3)}`
    const connectUrl = `mqtt://${host}:${port}`
    init({
          size: 10000,
          defaultExpires: 1000 * 3600 * 24,
          enableCache: true,
          sync: {},
       });
    export default class TestScreen extends Component {
    
      constructor(){
    super();
    this.onMessageArrived = this.onMessageArrived.bind(this)
    this.onConnectionLost = this.onConnectionLost.bind(this)


    const client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(connectUrl, port, clientId,);
    client.onMessageArrived = this.onMessageArrived;
    client.onConnectionLost = this.onConnectionLost;
    client.connect({ 
      onSuccess: this.onConnect,
      useSSL: false ,
      userName: 'User',
      password: 'Pass',
      onFailure: (e) => {console.log("here is the error" , e); }

    });

    this.state = {
      message: [''],
      client,
      messageToSend:'',
      isConnected: false,
    };

  }


  onMessageArrived(entry) {
    console.log("onMessageArrived:"+message.payloadString);
    this.setState({message: [...this.state.message, entry.payloadString]});

  }


  onConnect = () => {
    const { client } = this.state;
    console.log("Connected!!!!");
    client.subscribe('hello/world');
    this.setState({isConnected: true, error: ''})
  };


  sendMessage(){
    message = new Paho.MQTT.Message(this.state.messageToSend);
    message.destinationName = "hello/world";

    if(this.state.isConnected){
      this.state.client.send(message);    
    }else{
      this.connect(this.state.client)
        .then(() => {
          this.state.client.send(message);
          this.setState({error: '', isConnected: true});
        })
        .catch((error)=> {
          console.log(error);
          this.setState({error: error});
        });
  }
  }


  onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
    if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
      console.log("onConnectionLost:"+responseObject.errorMessage);
      this.setState({error: 'Lost Connection', isConnected: false});
    }
  }




  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native MQTT!
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Message: {this.state.message.join(' --- ')}
        </Text>
        <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>
          {this.state.error}
        </Text>
        { this.state.isConnected ?
            <Text style={{color: 'green'}}>
              Connected
            </Text> : null
        }
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.messageToSend} 
          onChangeText={(value => this.setState({messageToSend: value}))} 
          placeholder="Type hereee..."
          style={styles.input} />
        <Button onPress={this.sendMessage.bind(this) } title="Send Message" />

      </View>
    );
  }


}
```

**Error :**

```
TypeError: (0, _reactNativeMqtt.default) is not a function. (In '(0, _reactNativeMqtt.default)({
    size: 10000,
    defaultExpires: 1000 * 3600 * 24,
    enableCache: true,
    sync: {}
  })', '(0, _reactNativeMqtt.default)' is an instance of Object)
```

Comment: Please do not post images of errors, post the actual text and then use the toolbar to format it. Images are hard to read, impossible to search for and also impossible for people that use screen readers.

Comment: @hardillb okay can you check it now

Answer (score 2):

This will not offer you a solution, just some hints which may or may not be helpful, but it's just too long to place in a comment.

1. This line: `const client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(connectUrl, port, clientId,);` I don't see `Paho` defined anywhere. You import `MQTT`.
2. You refer to another answer, but that was using a different MQTT library -- **react_native_mqtt**, and you're using **react-native-paho-mqtt**
3. The `Client` constructor is documented to take 4 arguments, and you supply 3 and there's a dangling comma. Was it a typo?
4. You can find perhaps a better example of client instantiation on this [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-paho-mqtt).

Comment: Thanks for your reply I update my question

Comment: Now that you've switched to **react_native_mqtt**, have you installed it with npm?

Comment: yeah I installed this version  "react-native-mqtt": "^0.1.0-beta4",

Comment: But it's a different library! you import **react_native_mqtt** but installed **react-native-mqtt**. I know it's super confusing, as there are many libraries with very similar names on npm.

Comment: Yeah there is a lot of similar names, I update my code now return an error [quest is updated]

Comment: You're still confused. Now, you're trying to use **react-native-mqtt** library as if it were **react_native_mqtt**. The former does not have an export named `init`. I would suggest not using **react-native-mqtt** at all, it's an old and apparently abandoned project, they say it themselves: "this repository not use for production". Research _all_ MQTT packages for React Native and pick the most solid one (popular and with low number of issues on GitHub).